# Restrictions of Lagrange's mean value theorem for derivative?

Tags: real-analysis, riemann-integration

How far can the Lagrange's mean value theorem for derivative be used to make the statement : if f is the derivative of some function on [a,b], then there exists a number $\xi\in{[a,b]}$ such that $$\int_{a}^{b}fdx=f(\xi)(b-a)$$

Comment: The derivative $f$ must be continuous. See this Wikipedia article: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem#Mean_value_theorems_for_definite_integrals

Comment: Why should $\int_a^b f$ even exist?